# Reading, writing and storing JSON with Node on Heroku

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, heroku, datastore

I am building an App based on Node.js running on Heroku.

The app uses a JSON file which at the moment is being pushed with the rest of the app, and we are reading and writing to it like so:

```
var channelsList = require("./JSON/channels.json");

...

fs.writeFile("JSON/channels.json", JSON.stringify(channelsList), onCleaned);
```

This has worked for now for the prototype, but I know that we need to use a data store or the changes won't persist when Dyno's sleep or I push changes.

I have read that setting up a DB with Mongolabs could be a good option, but I was wondering if there are any other options, as this seems maybe more complicated than necessary. This is new territory for me, so if Mongo is the way to go, pointers would also be appreciated.

We also want to write new files as backups for each day of the week.

Cheers.

Comment: How about putting that file in `.gitignore`?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Elaborate?

Comment: Your Heroku app should be stateless. It might seem silly to connect to a database to persist what amounts to a single file, but that's how you keep your data separate from your runtime and this setup has a lot of nice benefits. I personally use MongoHQ (they also have a Heroku add-on) when I need MongoDB. It might take you a moment to set it up and figure it out, but it's something that you should know for this exact purpose. And it'll take you 5 minutes next time. Tip: Try connecting your local/dev app to one MongoHQ instance and your production app to another MongoHQ instance.

Comment: @danneu I think I will try setting up a MongoDB then, it will be good to learn for sure. Do you have any resources / tutorials you know for setting this up, I have zero experience with this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Disclosure: I am the node.js platform owner at Heroku.*

**You will need to bring the state out of your application.** For replacing JSON files in a node app, you should look at mongo, s3, and redis:

- **mongo**: feature-rich and reasonably fast
- **s3**: abstraction that maps best to 'filesystem' storage (take care with permissions)
- **redis**: simple and fast

Personally, I prefer redis for simple use cases (it sounds like yours might qualify). You can just dump JSON in and parse it out. Alternatively, the most popular redis client for node provides a friendly interface for simple hashes:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#friendlier-hash-commands

Redis, mongo, s3:

- https://elements.heroku.com/search?q=redis
- https://elements.heroku.com/search?q=mongo
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have decided to use Mongo... it's maybe overkill for the data we have now, but really useful to learn, and good if we scale in future.

Comment: So in short: you cannot create files on heroku, can you? That brings me right to the question about user file uploads etc.

Comment: @prc322 you can create files on Heroku. They will exist, in a container, as part of an ephemeral file system - so are not appropriate for long-term storage (but are fine for processing user uploads, though in node it's frequently a better idea to process uploads as streams).

Comment: @hunterloftis I agree on using the streams api(s) when it comes to user uploads but the rest of your answer leaves me confused: regardless of how the files get uploaded, they end up as files in your app and its filesystem.  And some of them will have to stay there for a long time (i.e. user profile pictures). What do I miss here?

Comment: @prc322 a good resource for this is http://12factor.net/processes, but here's the tldr: imagine that user's profile picture uploaded to server1, on server1's file system. Now you get more users and need to scale out, so you add server2. server2's filesystem doesn't have the user profile pic, so when your router sends people to server1 they can see that user, but server2 shows a broken image. Instead, a horizontally-scalable app should use shared services for state. For files/images, the most popular is Amazon S3 (or https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer for the addon version).