# Discordjs web dashboard with json

Tags: json, heroku, discord, discord.js

is possible to host a discord bot (made with discord.js) on heroku using json as a database?
All suggestions is appreciate.
Thx in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but JSON shouldn't be used as a replacement for a database. Heroku provides a [Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) database.

Comment: thanx for suggestion, i use json because it's confortable.

Comment: **JSON is not a database** in the first place, it's a serialization language. Heroku's filesystem is ephimeral meaning you can't actually have persistent changes to the fs across sessions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to [host a discord bot using Heroku](https://medium.com/@mason.spr/hosting-a-discord-js-bot-for-free-using-heroku-564c3da2d23f) and it is possible to utilize JSON files for data storage for a `discord.js` bot. However, they do not mix well as is discussed with the Node.js platform owner at Neroku [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747422/reading-writing-and-storing-json-with-node-on-heroku).
It is generally not recommended to use a JSON file as a 'database' and is especially not a good practice with Heroku for the reasons described in the comments to your question.
Try to use Herokus [Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres). Learning how to use databases and getting comfortable with them will help you in the long run.

The Heroku guy in the second link also recommends `redis` for its simplicity when working with JSON objects, so that might help as well.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion!