# Heroku with .json files as databases

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js, heroku, server

I have a simple webshop (https://github.com/markec15/KODIUS/tree/main) where I store products in .json file. This works perfectly fine in testing env but when I push it to heroku it doesn't work. Do I have to use real database for heroku or is there something I can do so heroku can use .json as databases.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Heroku will remove any files created by the application, so you should not rely on the filesystem.

You could use S3 if you want a file system (there's a free tier and Heroku has some [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) about how to integrate with it).

Other great options are MongoDB or Redis.

This answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769708/15484839